# Hello World App not working on samsung phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to run a simple app created on android studio on my samsung phone. When I run the program it gives an error "Android resource link failed".

The goal is for the app to show up on my phone as "Hello world".

I've tried removing my phone and reconnecting the USB cable.
I've tried restarting my phone.
I've closed and re-opened android studio.
I am able to see my phone folders on my laptop which is a sign that there's communication between my laptop and the phone.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just check the "dimension resource" of values given to `padding` attributes (they are determined by red textColor).
you can find them in `res>values>dimensions` folder, which is seen in the left pane of android studio.

The resource names may be corrupted or they might not exist.

Otherwise rebuild the project; you can find this option on the top toolbar: `build>rebuild project`